# Make android layout and nested layouts within zoomable

Tags: android

I've been working on an app with complex layouts. I recently realized I need to make parts or all of my layouts zoomable.

One of my main xml files has a linear layout with multiple layouts nested within it to positions views properly. Is there an easy way to make this linear layout and everything within in zoomable? Or would it be easier to make the entire layout file zoomable? What are my options?

Answer (score 4):

First of all extend that class with that specific view

```
   public class MyImageView extends ImageView{
```

Override following method .

```
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);
 canvas.save();

 canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
 if(appInitialized) {

 hsSide.draw(canvas);
 scaleA.draw(canvas);
 scaleB.draw(canvas);

  }

 canvas.restore();


}
```

Create a Gesture Detector that will detect size of zoomed object and you can limit to avoid overlaps.

```
       private class ScaleListener extends    ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

 @Override
 public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

  mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
  pivotX = detector.getFocusX();
   pivotY = detector.getFocusY();
     // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
   mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.8f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 2.0f));

    invalidate();
   return true;
   }
 }
```

At the end initialize the object

```
    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;



   mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
```

Comment: Will this work if the root layout i"m trying to do this to is not an imageview? it is a layout with other views and layouts inside it

Comment: You can extend that with any view class . The scale gestrue will detect size of view and you can restrict that to overlap another view accordingly.

Comment: So I am supposed to use this to extend from my activity that starts the layout?

Comment: Since Java does not allow extending multiple classes . You activity class will remain same. You will need to create another view class that will extend view class . Then  call constructor of your new view class to activty class.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at static transformations.  Any `ViewGroup` or subclass can be customized to apply a transformation to its child views.  You enable this by calling `setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true)`, and then overriding the `getChildStaticTransformation()` callback ([docs link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildStaticTransformation%28android.view.View,%20android.view.animation.Transformation%29)) in your custom `ViewGroup`.  You can apply any transformation you like, including a scale to create your zoom effect.  This callback will be called any time the view needs to be redrawn or is invalidated.

Also, beware when using this alongside hardware acceleration.  Depending on the frequency with which you need to update the transformations you may find hardware doesn't quite work to redraw as you expect.  If so, you will need to enable software layers for this view hierarchy.

Comment: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261527/resizing-scaling-down-android-widgets-datepicker-and-timepicker)